# How can I set the color of activited Tab in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I hope to change the color of activited Tab in Android Studio, you can see Image A.

How can I do?

**Image A**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for mac here it goes

```
Android-Studio - Preferences - Editor - Color Scheme - General - Editor - Tabs - Selected tabs
```

and for Linux

```
File - Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - General - Editor - Tabs - Selected tabs
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it doesn't work for Windows 10.

Comment: I am unable to test it on Windows